# Cannot read property 'ARROW_DOWN' of undefined in protractor

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, protractor, automated-tests, jasmine-node

I am using **action sequences** in protractor while running my spec i am facing this issue can anyone help why this is happening and how to solve it.

Below is my spec code:

```
describe("Actions demo", function(){
    it(" Open website ",function(){
        browser.get("http://posse.com/");
        element(by.model("userInputQuery")).sendKeys("river");
        browser.actions().mouseMove (element(by.model("locationQuery")))
            .sendKeys("London").perform()
        browser.actions.sendkeys(protractor.key.ARROW_DOWN);
        browser.actions.sendkeys(protractor.key.ENTER).perform();
    })
})
```

Comment: What is the issue?

Answer (score 0):

You should use `protractor.Key.ARROW_DOWN` instead of `protractor.key.ARROW_DOWN`.

You are using `key` with lowercase instead of `Key` with uppercase.

It should also be  `browser.actions().sendKeys()`, `actions()` with parenthesis.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Silvan response, remember to use `.perform()` at the end every usage of `.actions()` otherwise it will not work.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please take the [tour], and read "[answer]" and its linked pages. Your answer is really a comment.

Comment: Yes, but I don't have the power to comment on another's answers so I added it here. What should be the action course in your opinion? @theTinMan

Comment: Silvan answer is not completed considering that if in Protractor you don't use .perform() for a chaininig secuence it'll fail silently.